# write function as sum of covectors

Tags: dual-spaces

I've got what should be a simple question. I have a function f(x,y) = 3x + 2y

The question asks to write this function as a sum of dual vectors. Any help on where to begin?

Comment: Can you add to your question what you think a *dual vector* is? Perhaps you can find a basis of dual vectors and express $f$ as a linear combination of the elements of that basis?

Comment: This is one of those cases where it's probably important to quote the question verbatim. There may be a requirement in the question that is more important than you think.

Comment: "where to begin" is with the definition of *dual vector* (or *covector* as it says in the title). What do those terms mean to you?

Comment: a) Suppose we have some linear function f : R
2 → R defined as f(x, y) = 3x + 2y. Write f as a sum
of dual vectors.

Comment: I think a dual vector is a complimentary vector that satisfies v^i*(vj) = kroenecker delta (i,j)

Comment: What's a complimentary vector? (or even a complementary vector?) What do $v^i$ and $v_j$ stand for? In any event, if you don't *know* what a dual vector is, then it's no wonder you can't solve the problem. So, the place for you to begin is by looking through whatever study materials you have to find out *exactly* what's meant by "dual vector".

Comment: Are you still here, Philip?

Comment: Yes I'm here a dual vector takes input of a vector and outputs a real number. It pulls out the component of the vector that aligns with it. It also gives Kronecker delta being 1 when components of both components of both the dual vector and the vector is the same and 0 otherwise

Comment: The word "component" only makes sense when you have specified a basis. Since no basis is specified, I take it we are assuming by default the "standard basis" $e_1=(1,0)$, $e_2=(0,1)$. Then the dual vectors are, as nole writes in an answer, $e^1$ and $e^2$ given by $e^1(x,y)=x$ and $e^2(x,y)=y$. So all you're being asked to do is to write $f(x,y)=3x+2y$ as a sum (though I would rather say, *linear combination*) of $e^1$ and $e^2$. So, can you do that?

Comment: Gone away again, Philip?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the dual vectors of the canonical basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Observe that $e^1(x,y)=x$ and $e^2(x,y)=y$.